# WPF, WinForms, ActiveX controls, and my vanishing sanity (calling DragMove() in response to a WinForms Control MouseDown event)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, interop

As you may have gathered from the title of this post, I am about to crack.

Ok, so here it is:  I have a WPF window which is hosting a WinForms Form which is in turn hosting an ActiveX control.  This is all due to legacy components and wanting to animate the opacity of a transparent WPF window.  Can't you just feel the fun already?!

...So, I would like to be able to drag my transparent WPF window by calling DragMove in mouse down for various areas of the window.  This works fine, and I can live with the current behavior, but it would be nice if I could also drag the window via a MouseDown event generated by my WinForms component.  So, I took the obvious approach:

```
void Init()
{
    MyWinForm form = new MyWinForm();
    form.SomeControl.MouseDown = form_MouseDown;
}

void form_MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
{
    if( e.Button == MouseButtons.Left )
    {
        DragMove();
    }
}
```

However, my application crashes with the following message:

> Can only call DragMove when primary mouse button is down.

Yeah, right, except the left (primary) button *is* the button being pressed (I realize this could be problematic for left handed mouses, but let's avoid that for now).  So, once again, simple code that works for a Mouse event generated by a WPF control fails for a `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.  Anyone have any experience with this?  Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

TLDR; Calling `DragMove()` from inside a `System.Windows.Controls.MouseDown` event crashes the app.  I'm open to any workaround at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `DragMove()` code using reflector, i've come to this solution: we can write or own `DragMove(IntPtr hWnd)`, which does not perform button state check, but we must explicitly release mouse capture in `MouseDown` event handler.

```
public static class Utility
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr h, int msg, IntPtr lp, IntPtr wp);

    public static void DragMove(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
        const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;

        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)0xf012, IntPtr.Zero);
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

and change your MouseDown handler just a bit:

```
void form_MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
{
    if( e.Button == MouseButtons.Left )
    {
        // it is necessary to release mouse capture, so that
        // WPF window will be able to capture mouse input
        ((Control)sender).Capture = false;
        // use helper to acquire window handle
        var helper = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(
            your_window_reference_goes_here);
        Utility.DragMove(helper.Handle);
    }
}
```

I didn't test it with ActiveX controls, but it works with simple WinForms control, hosted in `WindowsFormsControlHost` at least on Win7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: Why do I always seem to forget about Reflector? ...Anyway, you sir have been very helpful. Thanks a lot, it works great and taught me something new. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            Window.GetWindow(this).DragMove();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation ?